# Vue Test Utils - Await promises for vee-validate tests taking increasingly long

Tags: mocha.js, chai, vue-test-utils, vee-validate

Our test suite includes a bunch of tests that ensure that out form vee-validate messages are displaying. To do this we create a wrapper:

```
wrapper = shallowMount(SetPasswordForm, {
      i18n,
      sync: false,
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        user: {
          emailAddress: 'afake@email.com'
        }
      }
    })
```

Set the data, click submit, and then `await flushPromises` to give vee-validate time for the warnings to show.

```
  it('renders minimum length error and has no match error', async () => {
    wrapper.setData({
      password: 'sut',
      confirmPassword: 'sut'
    })

    wrapper.find('button.primary-action-btn').trigger('click')
    await flushPromises()

    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include('This field has a min length of 10')
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.count()).to.equal(2)
  })
```

However, we do this a lot throughout the application and every test that uses `await flushPromises` takes increasingly long to run. I'm talking an increase of about 100ms every test. We have 180 unit tests and the final tests in the suite take up to 3 seconds to run.

Is that normal? I don't think it is. Are we calling `await flushPromises` too often? Is this a problem with our test suite or is it actually a memory leak?

**Edit:**
Github issue: https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/2095